# Should I use "or" or "nor" in the following case?

Tags: grammar

> I wasn't forcing myself to say anything, or/nor trying to be funny.

"Or" sounds more grammatically correct to me. But "nor" has more Google results. So I'm confused.

Comment: Could you show us exactly what you mean by "more Google results"?

Comment: This https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+wasn't+forcing+myself+to+say+anything%2C+or%2Fnor+trying+to+be+funny.%22&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22++anything%2C+nor+trying+to+be+funny.%22 vs this https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+wasn't+forcing+myself+to+say+anything%2C+or%2Fnor+trying+to+be+funny.%22&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22++anything%2C+nor+trying+to+be+funny.%22

Comment: Uh, I think there's something wrong in that search.

Comment: As the sentence stands, I would use _or_. Now, if there were to be a period connecting the two parts as different sentences, then _nor_ would be a better fit: _I wasn't forcing myself to say anything. Nor was I trying to be funny_.

Comment: @ janoChen: Those Google searches are pointless. The particular word ***anything*** has no relevance whatsoever to the grammar of your example - it could just as well have been *forcing myself to say **something***, but it wouldn't make any difference to the grammar if you'd had some completely different activity there, such as *"I wasn't trying to impress the other people, or..."*

Comment: @janoChen: Those google search results both say "No results found".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Garner in his *Modern American Usage* (p571) would recommend **or** in Op's sentence. As Garner states:

> When the negative of a clause or phrase has appeared at the outset of
> an enumeration, and a disjunctive conjunction is needed, **or** is
> generally better than **nor**. The initial negative carries through to all
> the enumerated elements-e.g:
>
> "There have been no bombings *nor* [read *or*] armed attacks by one side against the other."
> William D. Montalbano,  "*Links to IRA Seen in Rash of Violence in Northern Ireland,*" L.A.
> Times 12 Jan 1996.

Peters, in the *Cambridge Guide to English Usage* (p378) has a more nuanced discussion:

> The use of **nor** is probably declining, even in its core domain of
> coordinating two negative phrases. Compare:
>
> - The gallery will not be open on Sundays **or** public holidays.
> - The gallery will not be open on Sundays **nor** public holidays.
>
> Both sentences are perfectly acceptable English, but the first shows
> that **nor** is not really needed to extend the negation over to "public
> holidays". Rather it may seem to overdo the expression of the negative
> for the purposes of a single announcement. This use of **nor** for the
> second coordinate underscores the parallelism of the two phrases, and in
> the context of fine writing, with more extended coordinates, it would
> seem to have its place. For example:
>
> "*The word universal is never the  name of anything in nature, **nor** of any idea or phantasm found in the  mind ...* "
>
> Substitute **or** for **nor** in that sentence, and the structure and
> meaning are still perfectly viable. The negative scope of *never*
> carries over to the second coordinate. But the use of **nor** helps to
> reaffirm the negative after a complex phrase, and to lift the latter
> part of the sentence.

The last point that Peters makes above endorses what FumbleFingers says in his or her answer.

---

Note of course that **nor** is mandatory if the sentence continues with a new clause:

> I wasn't forcing myself to say anything, nor was I trying to be funny.

Answer (score 7):

It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to use ***nor*** or ***or*** here, but my guess is the vast majority would opt for ***or***. If we consider a simplified version (still using "continuous" verb participles, but without the syntactically-irrelevant adjunct clauses)...

> *I wasn't shouting or arguing*

...I think almost no native speakers would use ***nor***. To my mind, the only real justification for using ***nor*** at all in such contexts is when the first activity (*shouting* in my example, *forcing myself to say anything* in OP's) is such a long phrase the reader might need "reminding" of the continuing negating effect of the initial ***wasn't*** when he finally reaches the point in the text where the *other* thing that I wasn't doing is reached. And I don't think that need particularly applies here.

Comment: That was the rule which I was trying to remember. But I would still use 'nor' in  the OP's example, just sounds more natural to my ear.

Comment: +1. I don't think I agree about it being *entirely a stylistic choice*, but the rest of the first paragraph I agree with, and it sure beats @WS2's answer, IMO. I also wonder about the purported use of *nor* to "remind" listeners etc. That sounds pretty far-fetched to me.

Comment: @Drew: If you don't think it's a stylistic choice, presumably you have some grammatical rule in mind that would *require* either ***nor*** or ***or*** here. I'd be truly fascinated to hear more about how this rule works. I'm being facetious, obviously - I think there is absolutely no possibility of any such rule. (But by all means please surprise me! :)

Comment: Your "*presumably*" does not follow logically. I am not convinced of the *stylistic choice* claim; that's all.  I have no rule to prove that it is not a stylistic choice.  And I agree with you that *almost no native speakers would use nor.*  My guess is stronger: that there would be **none** who would use *nor* here.  But guesses about 100%/0% are often inaccurate.

Comment: @Drew: I don't understand. Obviously WS2 (a native speaker) actually *prefers* ***nor*** in this exact context. And it's easy to construct shorter or longer versions of the same basic construction, which steer us more definitively towards ***or*** or ***nor*** respectively. If the first "denied action" had been, for example, *"wasn't forcing myself to say anything that would make them think I was a great fan of opera"*, I myself would probably lean more towards ***nor*** (because I'd definitely want to restate the implied main verb *"...nor **was I** trying to be funny"* after that long gap!).

Comment: *I was not doing this,* ***nor was I*** *doing that* is **correct**, as is *I was not doing this* ***or*** *that.*  What I think a native speaker would **not** say is *I was not doing this nor that.* See @Edwin's comment to WS2 - I agree with Edwin. (We need not agree.)

Comment: @Drew: I don't think we're *going to* agree! :) But see my comment to WS2's answer - by introducing alternative usages which repeat the main verb (*nor **was I***) you're changing the syntactic form of the utterance, so it doesn't tell us anything about what works in OP's context where the main verb is *not* repeated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Both *I was not doing this, nor was I doing that* and *I was not doing this or that* are equivalent to *I was not doing this,* ***and*** *I was not doing that.* But *I was not doing this nor that* sounds meaningless to me. You can prefer to say that it only sounds awkward, and that most native speakers would not say it. To me it sounds downright incorrect, but I have no proof that it is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: With your last comment I agree - both parts. (1) It is not appropriate to introduce "*..., nor was I...*" here, as if it were equivalent, and (2) I don't think we are going to agree (beyond this). ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Either is potentially possible: it essentially depends on where you want to place the "not" in the imaginary structure of your sentence. You can have a single negative ("not"/"n't") that negates both constituents:

> wasn't ( .... or ....)

or a negative for each constituent:

> was (not ... nor ....)

I would concur with FumbleFingers that, of the two choices, the first is probably more idiomatic in everyday native speaker usage.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'nor' in this instance.

*It wasn't Jane who told me, nor was it Samantha.*

*I have never been there on a Saturday, nor on a Sunday*.

*he didn't expect to win a gold medal, nor, for that matter, a silver or bronze*.

In this last example I feel sure it should be 'or' between silver and bronze, but I am struggling to recall the rule which determines that.

Comment: I wasn't singing nor dancing?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - you're going to the wrong places then...

Comment: I don't buy that "correct" assertion. Here are 234 written instances of the syntactically-identical ["not breathing or moving"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not+breathing+or+moving%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books. There's not a single instance of ["not breathing **nor** moving"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not+breathing+nor+moving%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), which doesn't surprise me in the least. In OP's context, ***nor*** is slightly more "justifiable", but personally I still much prefer ***or*** there too.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In that example I might use either depending on the specific nuance. Let's say I was trying to emphasise how quiet I had been. Whilst admitting I had made some noise, I might add - 'I wasn't singing or dancing'. However if I were supposed to be taking part in a talent competition and discovered that they had failed to enter me for anything I might complain, 'I wasn't singing, nor was I dancing. Why did they bother to invite me?'

Comment: @ WS2: In both your answer and that comment, you justify ***nor*** using examples which repeat the syntactic element ***was I/was it***. Without that (which doesn't reflect OP's example), *'I wasn't singing **nor** dancing. Why did they bother to invite me?'* doesn't look at all like a good context for ***nor*** to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is that I want to emphasise that they had failed to enter me for either. 'I wasn't singing, nor dancing - neither!' Were I complaining more generally about the poor organisation, I suppose I might say 'I wasn't singing or dancing'.

Comment: But that's exactly my point! When the two "denied actions" are reasonably short ***and*** semantically closely connected *(forcing oneself to say something, trying to be funny)*, that steers us towards using ***or*** because there's no reason to want to call attention to the fact that *not only did you not do the first thing - you didn't do the second thing **either***. When the activities are that easily linked *("I don't smoke or drink")* there's normally no reason to emphasise their "separateness".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think what we are discovering here (you may have known all along) is that, to a large extent, 'nor' is used when there is a need to emphasise the second and subsequent negatives.

Comment: @ WS2: I didn't consciously know that all along, but it became clear to me part-way through this comment thread. Normally, ***nor*** is paired with ***neither*** - and just like non-negated ***either/or***, it emphasises the fact of there being ***another** [excluded] alternative*. But ***nor*** still has that "emphatic" sense if used in a non-paired context (unlike ***or***, which is largely equivalent to ***and*** in a negated context).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree absolutely. One sees the value of these threads.